# how to create xml file in android

Tags: android

I want to create a xml file in android but i found an error as "File or Directory not found". Can any one help me please.
Here is the code:

```
package com.ex.createXml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class createXml extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    File newxmlfile = new File("C:/new.xml");
    try {
        newxmlfile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e("IOException", "Exception in create new File(");
    }

    FileOutputStream fileos = null;
    try{
        fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
         Log.e("FileNotFoundException",e.toString());
    }
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();

    try {
      serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
      serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
      serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
      serializer.startTag(null, "root");
      serializer.startTag(null, "Child1");
      serializer.endTag(null, "Child1");
      serializer.startTag(null, "Child2");
      serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
      serializer.endTag(null, "Child2");
      serializer.startTag(null, "Child3");
      serializer.text("Some text inside child 3");
      serializer.endTag(null,"Child3");
      serializer.endTag(null,"root");
      serializer.endDocument();
      serializer.flush();
      fileos.close();
      //TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.);

    } catch(Exception e) {
         Log.e("Exception","Exception occured in wroting");
    }
  }
}
```